# Excel filter duplicate items in column and sum values

Tags: excel

For example:

```
|Apples|2|
|Apples|3|
|Pears |4|
|Pears |2|
```

Would result in:

```
|Apples|5|
|Pears |6|
```

But they are not grouped like this.

I've been asked to do this for a friend, I'm a Linux user and I'd usually do this kind of thing in Python, but they need it in their Excel spreadsheet.  I'd expect a VB macro would be the way this is done, but any method is fine.

Answer (score 2):

No Need for **VBA**.

This will work just fine:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,C1,$B:$B)
```

assuming your raw data is in columns A,B and your single fruit items are in column C and your formula is in Column D. Then you can fill the formula down the column against the single items in column C. You can also attach row limits to the `A:A` and `B:B` range, if you wish.

Another easy solution is to use a `pivot table` to sum the data by the groups.